# Html duplicado con wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, html, pdf

Estoy implementando una conversión de HTML a PDF con **wkhtmltopdf**, tengo dos problemas:

1. No me respeta los estilos de HTML
2. El principal y mayor, me está poniendo el contenido muchas veces.

Adjunto código:

```
Process process;
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~"), "Utilities", "wkhtmltopdf", "wkhtmltopdf.exe");
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\";

// run the conversion utility
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

// note: that we tell wkhtmltopdf to be quiet and not run scripts
string args = "-q -n ";
args += "--disable-smart-shrinking ";
args += "";
args += "--outline-depth 0 ";
args += "--page-size A4 ";
args += " - -";

processStartInfo.Arguments = args;

process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

using (StreamWriter stramWriter = process.StandardInput)
{
    stramWriter.AutoFlush = true;
    stramWriter.Write(myHTML);
}

//read output
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
byte[] file;
int read = 1;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{

   while (read>0)
    {
         read = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

         memoryStream.Flush();
        // memoryStream.Position = 0;
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
   }

    file = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

process.StandardOutput.Close();
// wait or exit
process.WaitForExit(60000);

// read the exit code, close process
int returnCode = process.ExitCode;
process.Close();

process.Dispose();
//se guarda el archivo

File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\test.pdf", file);
```

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes, define: "No me respeta los estilos de HTML", ¿Cómo se visualiza?

Comment: Por ejemplo si le pongo color no se ve, se ve como texto sin formato

Comment: ¿Lo estás ejecutando en local o en el server? Ten en cuenta que todas las referencias deben ser locales, es decir, si usas CDNs o librerías externas, dichas fuentes deben ser aceptadas en el IIS (Esto lo haces ejecutando el código en el webserver) Si es una aplicación web, abre Internet Explorer en el webserver, ejecuta el procedimiento y agrega a la lista de excepciones las URL de tus referencias externas de CSS. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregas datos sobre el HTML que deseas convertir en PDF, por favor?

Comment: ya me acepto los colores usando <font color> </font> al parecer no acepta <style> , mi mayor problema es lo de que repite  todo, el codigo html varia de acuerdo al caso, pero es un codigo simple con <p> y <h3>

Comment: me parece bien raro, tengo styles y hasta javascript que modifica html, utilizo el mismo core (wkhtmltopdf) para la generación de PDFs, podrías agregar el HTML que deseas generar por favor :D

Comment: podrias poner el codigo q usas para generarlo? el problema no es tanto lo de los style sino q esta duplicando el codigo

Comment: No, porque utilizo Rotativa que es un wrapper de wkhtmltopdf,  utiliza el ejemplo completo que estás haciendo, te hace falta lo demás: https://gist.github.com/sm-abdullah/37ce7f05dc8ce7501e82

Comment: @fredyfx esta igual, es solo la primer funcion, a la segunda le tienes que enviar un html en archivo por ruta, y si, solo le modifique el ciclo, pero el hacer el ejemplo tal cual me hace lo mismo de escribir muchas veces

Comment: No he dado con la solucion, pasa cuando es un html muy grande, por ejemplo que genere mas de 2 paginas de pdf